# Break out from a "super function" from a callback

Tags: javascript, callback

I was wondering if it was possible to break out from a "super function" from a callback function.  I simplified my code to be more readable

```
function isClicked() {
   var userInputs = $("input");
   userInputs.each(function (index, element) {
      if ($(element).val() === "")
         return; //But I want to break out from isClicked()
   });  
}
```

I instinctively wrote this code, but I quickly realized that my reasoning was wrong, returning only broke from the current iteration of the callback.

So basically, my question is if it is possible to break out from isClicked() within the callback.

There is a easy fix to my problem, but I was wondering if the above was even possible

Comment: You can't do that. `return` is per function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Returning false stops the .each() from continuing to iterate:

```
function isClicked() {
   var userInputs = $("input");
   userInputs.each(function (index, element) {
      if ($(element).val() === "")
         return false; //Returning false ends the .each() iterating
   });
}
```

The code provided in the question doesn't need one, but I've sometimes needed to do something like the following with nested loops (not needed in the case provided):

```
function isClicked() {
   for (i=0;i<variable.length;i++) {
      var userInputs = $("input");
      var done = false;
      userInputs.each(function (index, element) {
         if ($(element).val() === "") {
            done = true;
            return false; //Returning false ends the .each() iterating
         }
      });
      if (done)
         return true;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So you could do using [jQuery's .eq()](http://api.jquery.com/eq/) :

```
function isClicked() {
   var userInputs = $("input");
   for(var i=0; i<userInputs.length; i++) {
      if (userInputs.eq(i).val() === "")
         return; //But I want to break out from isClicked()
   });  
}
```

Comment: yeah, I just ended up using a loop

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand why you want to break out from the main function, anyway the execution will stop, once the each loop completes.

**Though you can correct the code, instead of returning nothing from the each loop which continues the loop, you can return false if you want to break the loop.**

> ($(element).val() === "")
>            return false;

```
function isClicked() {
   var userInputs = $("input");
   var returnval = userInputs.each(function (index, element) {
      if ($(element).val() === "")
         return false; //But I want to break out from isClicked()
   });  
   return "something"; //return something or nothing
}
```